# How to get only the required elements from a string array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a array of strings from which I want only elements that are required by the user. The string array is as follows:

```
 const char* string2[]={"•-","-•••", "-•-•","-••", "•", "••-•","--•","••••","••","•---","-•-","•-••",
                       "--","-•","---","•-•","--•-","•-•","•••","-","••-","•••-","•--","-••-",
                       "-•--","--••","•----","••---","•••--","••••-","•••••","-••••","--•••","---••",
                       "----•","-----"," "};
```

I created a logic from which I will be able to get the numbers of string array that are required by the user but I am unable to get the correct output. The problem is say for example I type Hello, I get the numbers as follows:[8 5 12 12 15]

now I want my output to be as string2[8]:••, string2[5]:••-•, etc.

what changes do I need to make to get it to work in this?

```
for(a[i]=0;a[i]<length;a[i++]){
        printf("%s\t",string2[i]);
    }
```

I have tried to get it to work but I am unable to please help.

Comment: you really need to include a [mcve] in your question cos currently there are lots of gaps in it. Like what is the array `a`? We could make a guess about it's purpose/type/contents, but it'd be better if we had some solid facts to work with.

Comment: a[i] is the array that converts the user input from letters into numbers (alphabetic order) which is then again compared with string2[] and get the required elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    printf("%s\t", string2[a[i]]);
```